# osmpgsql fails to load all data from OSM file

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have a project where I need to use osm2pgsql to load an OpenStreetMap file (osm.pbf).
(Using a command like this:

```
osm2pgsql -c -d database_name -U user -H localhost -W -S "path to style file" "path to osm-file")
```

The command runs with no errors, but whenever I use it for larger areas, data on relations are not imported (the table for relations is created in Postgres, but it is empty). Same thing for the road table. It works fine for smaller areas.

Any ideas as to what the issue might be and, how I can fix it?

Comment: Please add console output

Comment: the relation table should only be created if you use the `slim` [option](https://www.volkerschatz.com/net/osm/osm2pgsql-usage.html). Are you using different options between the small/large file?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the roads table was created but empty, and that relations were not included at all. I was using the same settings for both the small and large file, but using the slim option worked! Thanks :)